# How can I get permission to translate and republish a book?

Tags: publishing, legal, copyright, translation

I am interested in translating an English book into my native language.

How can I get permission to translate the book? Would that also include permission to republish the book in the native language or is it another process?

Answer (score 11):

The book's copyright page will identify who owns the copyright to the material. This will typically be the author, or the publisher, or both.

Contact the copyright owner and negotiate to obtain the rights.

If you need more than that,
see  *[The Copyright Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1413324266),*
which has a chapter on how to obtain copyright permissions.

Comment: In the event that the book is self-published and the author holds the publishing rights, you may have to contact the author directly.

Comment: "Copyright owner" is a superset of "author or anyone they sold some of the rights to."